# What is the name of this input?

Tags: input-device, peripherals

What is the name of this input?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a very old DIN plug.

Comment: Looks like a DIN-8 connector. https://console5.com/store/din-connector-plug-8-pin-c-style-270-in-line-male-solder-cup-din8.html

Comment: Thank you **MrLister** and **JakeGould** , I was looking for XLRs variants. It is for a old and very unique audiology equipment. Need to replace the headphones. Thank you!

Comment: DIN & XLR aren't interchangeable - unless you mean to make up your own cable.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think I expressed myself wrong. I meant that I was searching on google as a XLR variant. Did not know that these DIN pins existed. I do not need them to be XLR.  Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @MrLister : It looks quite similar to PS2 connector,can you tell me how to differentiate it from PS2?

Comment: @Valay_17 They differ in size. The outer diameter of the [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) was 13.5 mm, the [PS/2 connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) 9.5 mm. They do look alike, because PS/2 is in fact a specialisation of [Mini DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector)!

Comment: @MrLister : Thank you for explaining, also the arrangement of the pins would differ if I am not wrong, right?

Comment: @Valay_17 The Wikipedia pages I linked to have drawings of the different arrangements.

Comment: @MrLister : Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [8-pin DIN plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) - weird and wonderful old stuff.

I could only guess at what the pinout might be, as there were at least [2 variants](http://www.hmarkstrom.se/kablar.htm), 8C and 8U.

You can still get these at any decent "radio spares" type store.

There are a few of the large concerns in the UK; Farnell, RS etc. I found [this list](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/circular-connectors/din-connectors/?sort-by=Number%20of%20Contacts&sort-order=desc&pn=4) from which [this one](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-connectors/0491061/) looks reasonably promising, but if you have a local equivalent store [warehouse], I'd take the old phones along with you and get them to figure out the pinout while you're there.

The thing about DIN plugs is their component similarity/replicability, so manufacturing is relatively simple.

The barrels, strain relief & even the pins are all identical. The only thing that changes is the face-plate [highlighted]… and even then some faces have more holes than they put pins through so you can use the same plate for many pin-counts.

[image]

Comment: Would I be able to get a DIN-8 to male P2(TRS) adapter? Will it work? 
I need both functionalities (audio and microphone).

Cannot find any DIN8 headphone (as in the image) here in my country. So I thought of using a DIN8 -> P2 adapter and then use a normal headphone instead

Comment: I'm almost certain you'd have to get cabling made up - no-one uses that stuff any more ;-) A bigger concern might be impedances. Again, I'm afraid I've no clue what those old structures used - I'd definitely take it along to a radio spares shop or a TV/audio engineer & get them to measure everything.